# Can Docker Desktop version work with Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, docker-desktop, container-runtime-interface

As far as I understand Kubernetes kubelet talks to CRI (Container Runtime Interface) to run containers. So every Container runtime which is being used in Kubernetes should follow CRI implementation (https://www.ianlewis.org/en/container-runtimes-part-4-kubernetes-container-run). Docker Desktop version neither runs dockerd or containerd. It runs HyperKit for High-Level virtualization. Is it CRI compliant and could be used with Kubernetes?

Answer (score 1):

Hyperkit is not CRI, it is hypervisor such as VirtualBox, which is used for `Docker Desktop for Mac`. From [Official docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/)

> Docker Desktop for Mac uses HyperKit instead of Virtual Box. Hyperkit
>   is a lightweight macOS virtualization solution built on top of
>   Hypervisor.framework in macOS 10.10 Yosemite and higher.

If you check this [blog](https://blog.docker.com/2016/05/docker-unikernels-open-source/), it explains very well relationships between hypervisors and CRI.

[image: Docker-Hyperkit-connectivity]

As you can see the above image, Docker Container Engine (or containerd) is in top of Linux kernel, so it has nothing to do with Hypervisors. This is basically the main difference between VMs and Containers. If you have Linux kernel, you can run your CRI there.

So, Docker Desktop with Hyperkit, will work with Kubernetes

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes.. got it. :)

Comment: So, as I understand this post, Docker Engine is running inside embedded linux (inside Hyperkit). On Mac only docker client binary and `/var/run/docker.sock` is exposed. `contianerd` and `containerd.sock` must be on Hyperkit embedded linux. Kubernetes installation on mac will figure out that CRI is docker from docker.sock and use docker client binary will execute all operations. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Partially yes, but Docker engine is not running inside embedded linux of Hyperkit, it is running in operating system of VM which created by Hyperkit(Hypervisor). If answer was useful, please accept it